# Scala classNotFound on Any type

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, scala-collections, scala-generics

I'm trying to make a generic value type in my HashMap like so:

```
val aMap = ArrayBuffer[HashMap[String, Any]]()
aMap += HashMap()
aMap(0)("aKey") = "aStringVal"
aMap(0)("aKey2") = true        // a bool value
aMap(0)("aKey3") = 23          // an int value
```

This works in my spark-shell but it gives me this ClassNotFoundException on scala.Any in my IntelliJ Project:

```
org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler logError - Error running job streaming job 1521859195000 ms.0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

I'm using Scala 2.11. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: In IntelliJ, the classpath isn't set to include the scala-libs?

Comment: The POM file includes scala library 2.11.

Comment: I have also seen this behavior inside Intellij when running  `someRDD.toDF`

Comment: @javadba - this was the hint I needed.  Wonder if you had the same problem I did - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

What this ended up being for me was creating a `DataFrame` with mixed data using `.toDF`

I had:

```
val baseDataFrame = Seq(
    ("value1", "one"),
    ("value2", 2),
    ("value3", 3)
  ).toDF("column1", "column2")
```

and this change fixed the issue:

```
val baseDataFrame = Seq(
    ("value1", "one"),
    ("value2", "2"),
    ("value3", "3")
  ).toDF("column1", "column2")
```